Powershell UIAutomation randomly works
I have the following powershell-script:
(The prerequisite is that Notepad++ is open)
Add-Type -LiteralPath "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\UIAutomationClient.dll"
Add-Type -LiteralPath "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\UIAutomationTypes.dll"

$app=Get-Process notepad++
$rootElement = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::RootElement 
$condition = New-Object Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition([System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::ProcessIdProperty, [int]$app.Id) 
$AppWindow = $rootElement.FindAll([System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Children, $condition)


$menuBarCondition = New-Object Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition([System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::ControlTypeProperty, [System.Windows.Automation.ControlType]::MenuBar) 
$menuBar = $AppWindow.FindAll([System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Descendants, $menuBarCondition)


$applicationmenu=$menuBar[1]
$menuItemCondition = New-Object Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition([System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::ControlTypeProperty, [System.Windows.Automation.ControlType]::MenuItem) 
$menuItems = $applicationmenu.FindAll([System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Descendants,$menuItemCondition)


$expandCollapsePattern = $menuItems[0].GetCurrentPattern([System.Windows.Automation.ExpandCollapsePattern]::Pattern)
$expandCollapsePattern.Expand()

All it does is that it opens the filemenu of notepad++. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When the problem occurs it's at the second or third FindAll-Method.
I do not know why this problem occurs sometimes.
I know that this task could be solved better with other approaches, but I need the access via this DLL in other tasks and there I observe the same thing.
What could be the cause and how could it be solved?
